# remove character " 's " in string

Tags: python, python-3.2

Suppose there are character `'s` at the end of word, how can I remove it?

Below, is what I tried:

```
st = "s'ss python's is fun's "
for ch in st:
    if ch[-2:] in "'s":   # check if last two index is 's
        st = st.replace(ch, "")
```

Output should be: "s'ss python is fun"

Somehow it will remove all `s` and `'`, not just at the end.

How can I just remove the character that have " 's ".

Comment: `for ch in st:` loops through each character, not the behavior you want.

Answer (score 2):

I think this accomplishes what you're looking for (sorry if I misunderstood :) ). This splits your string on whitespace and then iterates through the resulting 'words'. If the word ends in `'s`, that part is removed; if not, the entire word is returned. The result is then joined with the space character to return a string:

```
In [16]: st = "s'ss a python's is fun's "

In [17]: ' '.join(s if s[-2:] != "'s" else s[:-2] for s in st.split())
Out[17]: "s'ss a python is fun"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mylist = []
strin = "s'ss hello you's"
mylist = list(strin)
mylist.remove[-1]
print str(mylist)
#the output will be as , "s'ss hello you'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use regular expressions, like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"'s\b", "", "s'ss python's ")  
"s'ss python "
```

(`\b` matches the beginning or end of a word)

Answer (score 0):

First, your `st` ends with a space - you probably want to remove this with either [`str.split`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) or [`str.lstrip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip):

```
>>> st = "s'ss python's is fun's "
>>> st = st.strip()
>>> print(st)
s'ss python's is fun's
```

Then to remove the trailing `'s` there are many different ways.

Using a regular expression is one tidy way:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("'s$", "", st)
"s'ss python's is fun"
```

Or you can check if the string ends with `'s` and remove the last two characters:

```
>>> if st.endswith("'s"):
...     st = st[:-2]
```

Do not use [`str.rstrip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to do this, as it may not act like you may expect:

```
>>> st.rstrip("'s") # Bad
"s'ss python's is fun"
```

Looks correct in this case, but as the docs explain, "[the] argument is not a suffix; rather, all combinations of its values are stripped". For example:

```
>>> "lots of ssssss's".rstrip("'s")
'lots of '
```